# React throwing an error saying that setTimeout is not a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, 3d, xtk

Im trying to use the XTK library in react and keeps telling me that the setTimeout function is not a function. My code seems to be pretty clean and it functions well if I just use it directly with the html. However Im trying to get it to work in a react component and it just fails straight up. Can anyone tell me what Im doing wrong or where I can look to fix this?

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99kQg.png)

code for the component:

```
import React from 'react';


import window from 'xtk';
// window.X is now available

export default class VtkGeometryRenderer extends React.Component {
  constructor (){
    super();
  }
  shouldComponentUpdate(){
    return false;
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    // create a new 3d renderer
    var r = new  window.X.renderer3D();
    //r.container = 'r';
    r.init();

    // create a mesh from a .vtk file
    var skull = new window.X.mesh();
    skull.file = 'http://x.babymri.org/?avf.vtk';

    // add the object
    r.add(skull);

    // .. and render it
    r.render();

  }
  render() {

    return (
          <div
              ref={(c) => {
              this.rootContainer = c;
            }}
          />
        );
};
```

Comment: why did you call xtk `window` ? what if you replaced `window` with `xtk`?

Answer (score 0):

Oh the npm package just adds `X` on the window namespace.

Change:

```
import window from 'xtk'
```

to:

```
import 'xtk'
```

This will add `X` to the existing `window` object, instead of reassigning it like you are doing with that import statement.

Comment: so that solves that problem, but now its saying Im missing a loader. From another problem to the next I suppose. Thank you for your answer though.